# PosEx not works in Design-Time Package

Tags: delphi, debugging, package, delphi-7, design-time

I have created a design-time package for my delphi7 IDE. I want a component on a form offer me some menu items in the context menu during design-time. When i debug the package, i can see that my code gets executed, but when it comes to a line using the built-in function PosEx, the behaviour confuses me. In the debugger, i can see that the text to search in contains the part to search for, but the function returns 0 anyway! And, if i execute this directly (instead of debugging the IDE using it in a project) it all works fine.

This is my code:

```
function RemoveLeftOverPlaceHolders( var PIO_sTemplate: string);
var nStartPos: integer;
const JPCG_FOREACH_START = '{%foreach ';
begin
  nStartPos := 0;

  repeat
    nStartPos := PosEx( JPCG_FOREACH_START, PIO_sTemplate, nStartPos ); // <-- nStartPos is always 0 !
    if nStartPos > 0 then begin
      ...
    end;
  until nStartPos = 0;
end;
```

Is it possible that the string types are changed during execution in the IDE? (any ansistring-unicode problem?)

Edit: I'm using GExperts and DelphiSpeedUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid... the answer stands right in the code... nStartPos is initialized with 0, whichs leads to a failing PosEx. Strange that it worked when executing the code out of a design pack...

Comment: Yep. It's even in the docs. :-) "**PosEx returns 0** if SubStr is not found, if Offset is greater than the length of S, or **if Offset is less than 1.**" (emphasis added) It shouldn't have worked in any case, though.